# Fullpage js mediaqueries

Tags: html, css, fullpage.js

I'm creating a full page js. I've 5 section, these 5 section have full of content. I've wrote the media query based on the width, but when I take it some devices with small height, the content lags to the next section, so the user can't see it.

The breakpoints I'm using are,

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 0px) {
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
@media only screen and (min-width : 1600px) {
```

I would like to know maximum and minimum possible height for each breakpoint, so that I can write the media query accordingly.

Edit**
Here is the HTML,

```
<div id="fullpage">
<div class="section" id="section0">
  <div id="bgslider-text" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
      <h2 class="animated fadeInRightBig option"> 
          Testing aa
      </h2>
      <h2 class="animated fadeInRight options">
          TEst
      </h2>
      <h3 class="animated fadeInRight opt">
          Animated text
      </h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="section" id="section1">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with your approach is that you are trying to target devices, all of whose heights you can't possibly know.  A better approach is to have just one mobile mode.  If you can post an HTML snippet representative of your problem, you might get a good answer.

Comment: Please see this link it will help you http://www.templatemonster.com/blog/css-media-queries-for-all-devices-and-browsers-including-ie7-and-ie8

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've included the HTML..

Comment: Why don't you use fullpage.js responsive options? This way autoScrolling will be turned off in small screen devices and you can even have sections bigger than the viewport using the class `fp-auto-height-responsive` in each section.

Comment: I've tried thoose, but in bigger screens, above 2000, the content seems to be only little.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I like to take when dealing with mobile versus desktop views is to actually conditionally render the HTML elements *themselves* rather than trying to style the DOM for everybody.

Here is a trick you can use to show/hide a div depending on whether the device is mobile or desktop:

```
<div class="hide-desktop>
    Desktop content goes here...
</div>

<div class="hide-mobile show-mobile">
    Mobile content goes here...
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.hide-mobile {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
    .hide-desktop {
        display: none;
    }

    .show-mobile {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

When the device has desktop resolution, the mobile `<div>` will be hidden.  When the device's minimum width drops to 480 pixels, the media query will kick in, hiding the desktop content while showing the mobile content.

I believe this approach is more powerful then trying to do a one-size-fits-all CSS approach.

Comment: So your DOM is almost twice the size to support responsiveness? That seems wrong... I know sometimes, for small parts of the site, that's what you have to do, but for the entire page?

Comment: For the app on which I currently work, the majority of the DOM worked for both desktop and mobile.  There were several cases where media queries alone did not get the job done.

Comment: Ideally a separate source file entirely could be loaded for mobile and desktop.  In cases of only one file I stand by this approach.